# Save the value of checked checkboxes in an array on submit Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The problem is that checked checkboxes return true, and not the value of input(type="checkbox").

[Array or responded checked or not checked items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTalW.png)

And i cannot store that in an array(cause i need to). Also I can't specify exactly every checkbox name on typescript cause the data is dynamically:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let resKeyFt of keyFeatures; let i = index" class="p-0" col-6>
      <ion-item>
             <label for="{{resKeyFt}}">{{valueFeatures[i]}}</label>
             <input id="{{resKeyFt}}" type="checkbox"
                    value="{{resKeyFt}}" name="{{resKeyFt}}" ngModel>
      </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

Or how can i save key of a "true" value in an array if it is not possible to get the value like this:

[Stored Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2JaM.png)

Comment: you need to bind array data?for checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
const obj = {
    a: true,
    b: '',
    c: true
};

const arr = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => obj[x])
console.log(arr) // --> ['a', 'c']
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, but in arrays are such as "type=text" inputs and it also returns the keys of them, not only the "true" keys. Is it possible to filter it and save just the "true" keys?

Comment: Sure, change the filter callback to `x => obj[x] === true`

Comment: Glad it helped ;)